# Javascript: Pathfinding in a (50000*50000 grid) 2d array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**The problem**

So, say one imagines a 2-d array of integer values which represents a gridded-map, like this:

`+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 10  |  2   |  2  |  4  | 656 |
+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 234 | 165  | 724 | 759 | 230 |
+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 843 | 734  | 999 | 143 | 213 |
+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 242 | 2135 | 131 | 24  | 374 |
+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 159 | 464  | 155 | 124 | 151 |
+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+`

The 2d indices represent the coordinates of a cell on the map, and the values in the array represent the relative difficulty to traverse the terrain of that cell - so for example 999 might be thick brambles, while 2,3,4  might be a slightly inclining path... or something.

Now we want to find the easiest path from [x,y] on the grid to [q,r] on the grid (where the sum of the steps is the lowest possible, in other words)

**The problem domain**

This needs to run in a modern browser, where a rather spartan map is rendered, and we'll draw a line from [x,y] to [q,r] through all the interceding vertices, after the user has input [q,r]. Conveniently, [X,Y] is always the same (say [0,0] for simplicity)

**So use Dijkstra's algorithm or A*!**

So my first instinct was to model the array as a graph, apply Dijkstra's algorithm and work from there. And in the above case, with a 5x5 grid, that works fine. I traverse each array index, and use the value, and adjacent values, to generate a node with weighted edges to all of it's neighbours. This builds up a graph which I can then apply Dijkstra's algorithm to.

However, In practice, I will be working with arrays up to **50,000 x 50,000** in size! That's 250 million!

So obviously building a graph on-the-fly to run Dijkstra’s algorithm isn't applicable. My next idea was to pre-compute the paths (The data-set is fixed), store them on the server and do a callback when we get the destination [q,r]...but this is 250,000,000 paths... even if I made it run in less than a second (which i don't think it will)  it'll take years to compute all the paths...

I think I might need to take another approach but I'm not sure, how can I make this work?

Comment: How did you model the array as a graph? You probably can take advantage of the grid structure...

Comment: check this article: [Fast and Accurate Estimation of Shortest Paths in
Large Graphs](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~sseufert/papers/aspsn-cikm.pdf)

Comment: it's 2 500 000 000, not 250 000 000

Comment: @sopel you're right, sorry! The scope has changed a few times as I've been working on this.

Comment: @StefanHaustein I generate the graph rather naively. I just traverse the array and create a graph for each index, then generate the weights of the edges based on the difficulty of adjacent indicies...make sense?

Comment: What does "spartan" mean? Are there gaps in the map? How do you store the map itself in the browser? If it's not sparse, it will consume a few Gigs of memory?

Comment: @stefan haustein Spartan means no frills. Don't worry about the rendering of the map. the problem I'm trying to address is simply path-finding in the array -  which can be done server-side if necessary.  
The array data itself is a CVS file generated by a GIS workflow that's read and traversed. 
A few gigs of memory server side is perfectly fine. It's not be able to  generate and storing a lookup table that's the blocker really.

Comment: Instead of using a 50k grid, you could first reduce the grid to maybe 5000 or 500 to make the initial searching faster. If the travel distances are generally very large (say 10k nodes) then a little inefficiency might be acceptable. Imagine trying to plot a route from Los Angelos to New York, you're not going to consider every road, you're going to look at highways and the quickest route on and off.

Comment: @halcyon I follow your reasoning, but I think in this instance, like my example above with the thick brambles, I don't think it would be effective. .

Comment: Let me restate my idea. You take the 50000sq values and group them together, in 4s, 9s, 16s etc. reducing the grid size until you get a value-set that you can operate on. This works well enough so long as there aren't any narrow paths inbetween high cost cells: if you have `| 999 | 1 | 999 |` for instance and reduce that to `| 1999 |` the optimal path will be lost. This approach is not going to give you the shortest path, because you're essentially losing resolution. It should give you a pretty-good-path.

Comment: @Halcyon yes your example illustrates it perfectly, this is exactly the kind of thing my dataset would have... Thank you for your suggestion though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't construct an explicit graph (pointers are expensive) -- use pairs of coordinates to represent nodes in the queue and modify your Dijkstra implementation to operate on your 2d array representation directly.

Use an array similar to the costs array to store the (initially tentative) distances calculated by the algorithm.

Dijkstra will calculate the costs to all nodes in a single run, so if your starting point is fixed, running it once should be sufficient -- there is no need to run it millions of times.

P.S.: Created a Jsfiddle running Dijkstra on images:
https://goo.gl/5GWwMF

Computes the distances to all points from a mouse click, where darker pixels are interpreted as more expensive...

It becomes slower with larger images but didn't manage to crash it so far, but I think for your data it will run out of memory in the browser.

The Dijkstra implementation uses the following interface to access the graph -- I think this should be straight forward to provide on top of your data structure without explicitly generating a "traditional" graph data structure with explicit nodes and edges in memory:

```
/**
 * The interface the Dijkstra implementation below uses
 * to access the graph and to store the calculated final
 * and intermediate distance data.
 *
 * @Interface
 */
Graph = function() {};

/**
 * Returns the current distance for the given node.
 * @param {Object} node
 * @return {number}
 */
Graph.currentDistance = function(node) {};

/**
 * Stores the current distance for the given node.
 * @param {Object} node
 * @param {number} distance
 */
Graph.setCurrentDistance = function(node, distance) {};

/**
 * Returns an array of connected nodes for the given node, 
 * including the distances.
 *
 * @param {Object}
 * @return {Array<{cost:number, node:Object}>}
 */
Graph.connections = function(node) {};
```

P.P.S.: Added code to display the shortes path on all clicks after the first click. Also fixed a bug permitting diagonal movement: https://goo.gl/wXGwiv

So in conclusion, while this probably doesn't scale to 50k x 50x in the browser, I think this shows that Dijkstra operating on the arrays directly is worth trying on the server side, and that an array identical in size to the data array is all that is needed to store all shortest paths from a single point.