# Routing in floor plan

Tags: algorithm, routes, graph-algorithm, indoor-positioning-system

I would like to design the indoor navigation system. The system allows the user to upload the JPG/PNG floor plan image. For routing creation, I have a rough idea. That is, I need to mark interchange point and create the relationship between them. The result like the following image:

[image]

After that, I can use the shortest path algorithm to create the routing path. However, if the user has not stayed in exactly interchange point, like the red circuit, how to create the routing path?

Comment: If the paths have a dedicated color, you might be able to route on the image directly. There was a similar question a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798373/javascript-pathfinding-in-a-5000050000-grid-2d-array

Comment: If the path goes to the right, color the part of arc from your initial red point to the next node on the right, if the path goes to the left likewise to the left.

Comment: @FrankS101 I don't know what you mean. My question is if the user stay in marked point, I can calculate the shortest path because my system know this point and the relationship with next point. However, the current problem is user stay in line or outside line. The inital user location point do not have relationship on next point.

Comment: I'm guessing you assume the graph's edges are the only feasible paths a user can actually take, so you can first find the geometrically closest edge. Once you have that figured out, treat the user's location as a new node, with two new edges to the nodes on the edge you've found.

Comment: @ShaharA You are correct. I have already got this idea. I can scan edge by radius. However, my problem is how to confirm which edge show in radius? It is because I only have (A,B) (B,A) knowledge in dataset.

Comment: @SinLok - I suggest you don't use radius, but calculate the perpendicular distance to the edges (which can simply be calculated with just the nodes coordinates), and select the closest one